# how to reassembled hierarchical data from a flat relation table?

Tags: python, relational-database

I'm trying to figure out how to translate a table that represents hierarchical data back into code.

The table is configured as such:

```
| id | parent_id | name | 
|----|-----------|------|
| 1  |   null    | foo  |
| 2  |    1      | bar  |
| 3  |    1      | baz  | 
| 4  |    3      | bif  | 
| 5  |    1      | zip  | 

etc...
```

Such that, when reconstructed, it looks like this:

```
foo
 |-bar
 |-baz
    |-bif
 |-zip
```

I'm struggling to find a non-terrible way to build this list up in memory.

Basically, the solution I've come to is just brute forcing my way through. e.g. (in pseudo Python)

```
output = {}
for item in table:
   parent = get_parent(item) 
   if parent: 
       if parent not in output:  
           output[parent] = []
       output[parent_item].append(item)
```

However, that only gets me half way. It correctly sticks the children under their immediate parent, but only *one* level up. This data is about 3 levels deep, so I guess I'd have to keep iterating over it until I couldn't find any more objects with parents.

Suffice to say, my solution is bad, brittle, and I don't know what else to do.. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this quick solution.

we can build a dictionary, so we can map keys with names.

```
D={"1":"foo","2":"bar","3":"baz","4":"bif","5":"zip","Non":'Root'}
get_parent_id=["Non","1","1","3","1"]
get_name=["foo","bar","baz","bif","zip"]

result = {} 
for k,v in zip(get_parent_id,get_name):
    result.setdefault(D[k], {}).update({v:{}})
```

we build a dictionary, from `parent ids` and names.

```
{'baz': {'bif': {}}, 'foo': {'baz': {}, 'bar': {}, 'zip': {}}, 'Root': {'foo': {}}}
```

Now, we have to work on the other values. we can use a boolean dictionary `{key:boolean value}` to mark which is the root here, whenever we find a value which is a key, we mark it as `false` as it couldn't be a root.

formally, `Root` is a keys that doesn't appear in the values of all the keys.

```
boolRoot= len(result)*[True]
bDict=dict(zip(result.keys(),boolRoot))

# {'Root': True, 'foo': True, 'baz': True}
```

Then, we traverse the values, and we replace the values inside with the key and the values that maps to children

```
for k,v in result.iteritems():
    for item in v.keys():
        #print item,result[k][item]
        if item in result.keys():
            bDict[item]=False
            result[k][item]=result[item]

print result
print bDict
```

At the end, we would have:

```
{'baz': {'bif': {}}, 'foo': {'baz': {'bif': {}}, 'bar': {}, 'zip': {}}, 'Root': {'foo': {'baz': {'bif': {}}, 'bar': {}, 'zip': {}}}} #result
{'Root': True, 'foo': False, 'baz': False} #bDict
```

The Root, is the key with value `True` based on the above-mentioned assumption. You need only to get `result[name]`, where `bDict[name] is True`

Hope it helps u come-up with better solution.